# Notation $\mathcal{F}_M$ where $M$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

The question arise from the question 4.4.3 on Durrett probability.

> Suppose $M\leq N$ are stopping times. If $A\in \mathcal{F}_M$, then
> \begin{align*}
> L = \begin{cases}
> M & \text{on $A$}\\
> N & \text{on $A^c$}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
> Then $L$ is a stopping time.

I don't get the notation $\mathcal{F}_M$. Moreover, in my opinion, $M,N$ and $L$ should correspond to the same filtration, but the question seems not. Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: $\mathcal F_M$ is the notation for a filtration generated by a stopping time (also called stopped filtration), in this case $M$. Have you seen the definition for this?

Comment: $M,N$ and $L$ are all stopping times with respect to the same filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge 0}$, as you thought. Now try showing $\{L\le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t,\,t\ge 0$ using the definition of $L$ and the fact that $A\in \mathcal{F}_M$ means (per definition of $\mathcal{F}_M$), that $$A\cap \{M\le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t,\quad t\ge 0.$$

Comment: @Peter Thats awesome, thanks!